# Should we have a tag for MDX? Where do MDX questions belong?

Tags: discussion, tagging, migration, scope

I answered [a question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17896/2848) today on Stackoverflow that was migrated to DBA.SE. I took a look at the FAQ and see that BI and Data Warehousing are on topic, but basic SQL is not.

The question is basic MDX, but that doesn't seem to be covered. Should we have an MDX tag here? Are basic MDX questions more on topic here than SO?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think MDX questions are probably closer to the mark here.  This is now the "official" B.I. site in the network.

I added the MDX tag to that question for you so it can be used in the future.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I agree this is a better fit.